# Cannot change opacity of Cocos2d-x MenuItemToggle elements

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, opacity, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to determine why opacity does not affect **CCMenuItemToggle** items? This is true when calling **setOpacity()** on the object directly as well as when calling actions such as **FadeTo()** or reducing the opacity of its parent.

I have tested this using Cocos2dx v2.2.6 and v3.8.1 and it is the same in both.

```
auto item1 = MenuItemToggle::createWithCallback(CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCallback, this),
    MenuItemImage::create("CloseNormal.png", "CloseNormal.png"),
    MenuItemImage::create("CloseSelected.png", "CloseSelected.png"),
    nullptr);

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
auto menu = Menu::create(item1, NULL);
menu->setPosition(256, 256);
this->addChild(menu, 1);

// Nothing I do to try and make 'item1' set to 0% opacity works. It is always 100% opaque.
menu->setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true);
menu->setOpacity(0.0);
item1->setOpacity(0.0);
item1->getParent()->setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

After further analysis, I discovered that calling `setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true)` on the MenuItemToggle itself is required for it to be affected by opacity (including when setting opacity via the parent Menu container). This behavior deviates from the other CCMenuItem classes and threw me off.

To alleviate the need to call SetCascadeOpacityEnabled(true) on every toggle item, one can alternatively set the options in the main CCMenuItem::initWithTarget constructor. i.e.,

```
bool CCMenuItem::initWithTarget(CCObject *rec, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
{
    setAnchorPoint(ccp(0.5f, 0.5f));
    m_pListener = rec;
    m_pfnSelector = selector;
    m_bEnabled = true;
    m_bSelected = false;

    // Make sure opacity and color values cascade to children
    this->setCascadeColorEnabled(true);
    this->setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```